# Showing that, under certain assumptions, $df_x$ has no eigenvalues on the unit circle

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f : M \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and $x$ a fixed point of $f$. Suppose that there exist a decomposition $T_x M = E^-_x \bigoplus E^+_x$ and constants $c > 0, \lambda \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$\|df^n_x(v)\| \leq c \lambda^n \|v\|, v \in E^-_x, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\|df^{-n}_x(v)\| \leq c \lambda^n \|v\|, v \in E^+_x, n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Show that $df_x$ has no eigenvalues on the unit circle.

My work: Suppose there is $\mu$ with $|\mu| = 1$ and $v \neq 0$ such that $df_x v = \mu v$. Then $\|df_x v\| = \|\mu v\| = |\mu| \|v\| = \|v\|$. On the other hand, from the Chain Rule and the fact that $x$ is a fixed point we have $df^n_x(v) = (df_x)^n(v)$. But I can't obtain a contradiction considering the two inequalities. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$df^2_x(v)=df_{f(x)}df_x(v)=df_x(\mu v)=\mu^2v$, recursively you obtain that $df^n_x(v)=\mu^nv$. Write $v=v_1+v_2, v_1\in E_x^-, v_2\in E^+_x$, $\|v\|=\|df_x^n(v)\|=\|df_x^n(v_1+v_2)\|$. Suppose that $v_2\neq 0$, we have $lim_n\|df_x^n(v_1)\|\leq lim_n c\lambda^{n}\|v_1\|=0$, $lim_n\|df^n_x(v_2)\|\geq lim_n c^{-1}\lambda^{-n}\|v_2\|^{-1}=+\infty$. This implies that $\|v\|=lim_n\|df_x^n(v)\|=lim_n\|df^n_x(v_1)+df^n_x(v_2)\|\geq lim_n(\|df^n_x(v_2)\|-\|df^n_x(v_1)\|)=+\infty$. Contradiction,

if $v_1\neq 0$, use the same idea with $f^{-1}$.